References for Maltsev's Theorem on $GL_n(F) \equiv GL_m(K)$ iff $K \equiv F$ and $m=n$.
I have recently found Maltsev's theorem: for $F$ and $K$ algebraically closed fields, $GL_n(F) \equiv GL_m(K)$ if and only if $K \equiv F$ and $m=n$ (thanks to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158583/is-it-ever-a-good-idea-to-use-keisler-shelah-to-show-elementary-equivalence ).
I want to know where I can find the proof of this theorem. I am aware that Maltsev first stated this result in the journal "Problems of Mathematics and Mechanics", Novosibirsk (1961) (On elementary properties of linear groups), but I am unable to find the document anywhere.

I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

I assume you meant $GL_n(F) \equiv GL_m(K)$ instead of isomorphic?

@DavidGao that's right, thanks for the correction!
